# help me please with this question from pdf book for logic tests

Tags: logical-deduction

please help find the answer. it says (translation from english to french)
complete the missing block with one block from 9 block below.[image]

Comment: Hi, new bie, and welcome to PSE! For puzzles that you didn't create yourself, you need to clearly credit the source, so please add the name and authors of the book to the question. Cheers, and happy puzzling.

Comment: 700 tests
psychotechniques
et de raisonnement
logique

Comment: author furet du Nord

Comment: Add these in your question @newbie

Comment: how? I'm new here

Comment: There are links between the question and these comments, just under the [tag:logical-deduction] tag. The second link says "edit".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is

> Option 3

Reason:

> The lines belonging to the square is rejected in the third picture if both first and second picture of a colum have that line in common. The semi-circles are always added. So, reject the diagonals and add the left, up and right lines of the square to the semi-circles (ovelap them and never reject them). Thus, you will get option 3.

Comment: This is about the same answer I got, the only problem is that there's no case in either of the other columns in which neither of the lines forming the square is present, meanwhile in the second column the bottom edge is in neither of the blocks. Therefore there's no way of telling whether that edge would be rejected or not.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I got, it led me to a 50/50 where it could go either way so there's either something I'm missing or I'm barking up the wrong tree, but my guess is that:

> In each column, the first two blocks have a logic operator for each element correlating to the third block in the column.

For the X in the center:

> It corresponds to either an XOR or NAND operator, we don't know since there's no case in which neither element contains an X, but we don't need to know to find the solution.

For the lines forming the square

> They also correspond to either an XOR or NAND operator, since in the first column the left side is fulfilled because it is in the first image, the top and bottom are fulfilled because they are in the second image, but the right side is not since it is in both. Again, we don't know since there's no case in which neither other column contains a side that isn't fulfilled by either, and this is an issue due to the bottom edge in the second column, and why I think this might be wrong.

For the curves on the outside

> They correspond to an OR operator, since in the first column each block has one on the bottom and one on the left, respectively, and the third block has both, and then in the third column both blocks have it on the left and right, corresponding to the third block.

Gleaning from this:

> We would expect the block to have no X in the middle, the top, left and right sides of the square, and possibly the bottom edge, and then the top and bottom curves. This corresponds to either answer 2 or 3.

Comment: Nice thinking though @MichaelMoschella

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is

> Option 3

Reason

> You solve this one by 'going vertical'. F ex the object in the 3rd row of the 1st column is the result of combining the objects in the 1st and 2nd row of the same column. Straight lines 'cancel' out each other if they're placed the same on the 1st and 2nd row. Arched lines do NOT cancel out each other even if they're placed the same in 1st and 2nd row. Same logic applies to the other two columns

Comment: I think adding row 1 and 2 and removing the lines that are superposed (keeping curves) . the answer should be 3